# libraries / services to assist with iOS wireless app distribution

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, distribution, over-the-air

Can anyone recommend any libraries/utilities they use to assist in distributing iOS adhoc/enterprise applications over the air, so users can install without needing a PC/iTunes?

There's a few hosted services around (eg. https://testflightapp.com/ - though that is not free for enterprise apps), but I'm sure in the past I saw a non-hosted service (ie. something I could install on my own server) and came with a client side library that was easy to hook into the app to notify the user when updates were available and allow them to easily install them. Unfortunately it seems I didn't bookmark it and a bunch of googling and searching on stack overflow hasn't found it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the one I believe I was thinking of when I wrote the question, it's called "Hockey":

http://hockeykit.net/

https://github.com/TheRealKerni/HockeyKit

If there are other similar solutions out there, please do add your own answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own manifest and bundle it with the app package (the IPA from Build and Archive). There are a lot of guides on the web. e.g. [this to automate OTA distribution using Heroku](http://www.hectorramos.com/automating-ios-over-air-beta-deployment) from Héctor Ramos or [Mike Nachbaur's write up](http://nachbaur.com/blog/building-ios-apps-for-over-the-air-adhoc-distribution).

That said, I suspect using TestFlight.app is a lot easier than rolling your own - have you looked at the cost benefit of paying TestFlight vs developing and maintaining your own system. Much better to write production code rather than save the cost of the TestFlight subscription surely...

Comment: Thanks Roger! I do have OTA working already (having rolled my own in the early days), just looking to improve it. Héctor's article does make interesting reading. I'm just not sure TestFlight is that close to what I want / need (and they seem to do their best to confuse me as to whether it works for Enterprise builds or not) - Hockey (see my answer) might be better for me. I'm sure there must be other solutions out there too.